# How to do hypothesis testing with real-valued data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

*Disclaimer: I don't mean real-valued data in the sense that the data could be any number in $\mathbb{R}$, I mean it rather in that there is no proportion/percentage.*

Let $A$ be a dataset that has $n$ samples of how many semesters students needed to graduate from college in school X in 1950, let's assume the mean is $\mu_A$. Let $B$ be a dataset with $m$ samples that contains how many semesters needed to graduate from college in school X in 2000. let's assume the mean is $\mu_B$, with $\mu_B>\mu_A$. Then, we formulate the null and alternate hypothesis as follows:

$$H_n=\text{Students need on average $\mu_A$ semesters to graduate in year 2000 in school X}$$
$$H_a=\text{Students need on average more than $\mu_A$ semesters to graduate in year 2000 in school X}$$

How would one go about calculating the p-values here? One way I thought of is: calculate the standard deviation of $A$, thus characterizing the distribution of $A$ (mean and variance are known), then I can use that distribution to calculate the likelihood of $\mu_B$. However, that way feels very wrong because I am not using $m$ or the standard deviation of $B$.

For p-values, I usually see the formula $z=\dfrac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{pq/n}}$, where the $p$s are proportions, and $n$ is the sample size of the dataset collected to presumably show evidence against the null hypothesis. However, I don't know how to apply that analysis in this case.

I would imagine there are tons of ways for doing this. I just haven't been able to find one. I'd appreciate if someone could explain or share some resources.

Comment: This is what I was looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test

Comment: Do you mean something "What's the total number of semesters of college students needed to take in 1950 vs 2000"? Because if you are instead comparing the number of *remaining* semesters in those two years, the answer to "how many semesters students will need to graduate" depends on the distribution of students per year (among several other things).

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are saying, but I'll try to reply. The assumption is that the curriculum hasn't changed, namely, perfect students need as many semesters in 1950 and 2000. The reason why there is a change is because the distribution of students changes and that is what I want to test.